# How do I modify the Django training project (poll voting system) so that it has a home page at the root of the domain?

Tags: python, django

This is the current files I am using based on the poll voting beginners tutorial

mysite/urls.py  (main app with a settings.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),

    path('', ?),
]
```

polls/urls.py  - Currently contains the following information. notice even though path("", ..) looks like "domainname.com/" root location, it is "domainname.com/polls/" is that became of the app_name = "polls" namespace?)
How do I add a mapping for the root of the domain (domainname.com/) so I can add my own homepage?

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "polls" # Namespace to url template tag can find correct url

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path("<int:question_id>/", views.detail, name="detail"),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path("<int:question_id>/results/", views.results, name="results"),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path("<int:question_id>/vote/", views.vote, name="vote"),
]
```

I have noticed some github projects are mapping the home page like so

videoapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("videos.urls")),
]
```

And mapping them to the view like so

videos/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# http://127.0.0.1:8000/
# http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
# http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos
# http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/1
# http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/video-1
urlpatterns =[
    
    path("",views.home,name="home"),
    path("home",views.home),
    path("videos",views.videos,name="videos"),
     path("videos/<int:id>",views.videodetails,name="details"),

]
```

However I cannot do this as it automatically is starting the url from 'polls/'. What is a good approach for me to add a custom homepage?

Edit: I've noticed many people are creating a separate app call 'home' or 'frontpage' for the soul purpose of having a homepage. It seems a little unusual to have an app just for 1 page or is this the norm?

Edit 2: The app I choose to have my homepage within cannot have any namespace applied Im guessing (cannot set app_name = "value")?

Comment: what is `mysite`? Project name or app name?

Comment: the app which contains the settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add custom homepage to your django project you should take these steps:

create a new view for your homepage in the main app's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

then create a new template file `homepage.html` for your homepage inside the `templates` folder in your main app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Custom Homepage!</h1>
    <!-- Add your homepage content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

and now update the main app's `urls.py` to include a path for the homepage:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views import homepage

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),

    path('', homepage, name='home'),
]
```

now when you navigate to the root URL it will display the custom homepage.

your structure should looks like this:

```
mysite/
|-- mysite/
|   |-- templates/
|       |-- mysite/
|           |-- homepage.html
|-- polls/
|   |-- templates/
|       |-- polls/
|           |-- index.html
|-- manage.py
```

and make sure that your `TEMPLATES` setting in your main app's `settings.py` is configured correctly:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],  # Add this line
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        # ...
    },
    # ...
]
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi Kiarash. Thank you for the code. I tried the approach you have provided but I seem to be getting a "TemplateDoesNotExist at /" error.  It is still looking for the template within the "polls" app. "/polls/templates/homepage.html".  By the way I had to change the from statement to "from .views import homepage" to get it to import

Comment: It seems to work if I add "mysite" to the INSTALLED_APPS global. I dunno if thats the right way to do it though

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope this works for you

Comment: I tried adding the os.pathjoin line to the TEMPLATES variable but without adding 'mysite' to INSTALLED_APPS django cant find the template (enough though the path is correct) Not sure if that is only with my setup. In any case it works adding mysite (which contains the settings.py) to INSTALLED_APPS and didnt require editing TEMPLATES